# How to use single .d.ts file generated from multiple ts files

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I wrote a React library using TypeScript and want to use it from another project. Using dts-generator, I generated a .d.ts file for multiple .ts files of this library (Project). ts file hierarchy under this project:

```
Project
 - src
  - actions
    Action.ts
    ActionTypes.ts
  - components
     // Some ts files
  - containers
     // Some ts files
  - reducers
    Reducers.ts
```

Generated .d.ts file looks like below after executing the command `dts-generator --name TurIDM --project . --out public/turIDM.d.ts` under Project folder.

```
declare module 'TurIDM/actions/ActionTypes' {
    export const ACTIVE_MENU_CHANGE = "ACTIVE_MENU_CHANGE";
    export const AUTHENTICATE = "AUTHENTICATE";

}
declare module 'TurIDM/reducers/Reducers' {
     const reducers: ReduxActions.Reducer<StoreState, any>;
    export default reducers;

}

// Rest of the module declarations...
```

I put this generated .d.ts file under the consumer project and
index.tsx in this project imports and uses some modules defined there:

```
ConsumerProject
 - public
    index.js
 - src
    index.tsx
 - turIDM
    turIDM.d.ts
    turIDM.js
 index.html
```

index.jsx:

```
import * as React from "react";
import * as ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from "redux";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { logger } from "redux-logger";
import {Route, Switch} from "react-router";
import { ConnectedRouter, routerMiddleware } from "react-router-redux";
import createHistory from "history/createBrowserHistory"
import reducers from "TurIDM/reducers/Reducers";
import Main from "TurIDM/containers/Main";
import Login from "TurIDM/containers/LoginContainer";
import {LOGIN_PATH, MAIN_PATH} from "TurIDM/util/Constants";

const history = createHistory();
const middleware = routerMiddleware(history);
const store = createStore(reducers, applyMiddleware(middleware));

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
            <Switch>
                <Route path={LOGIN_PATH} component={Login}/>
                <Route path={MAIN_PATH} component={Main}/>
            </Switch>
        </ConnectedRouter>
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById("main")
);
```

turIDM.js and index.js (generated from index.jsx by webpack) are added in index.html:

```
<html lang="en"<head</head<body <div id="main"></div    <script
   src="turIDM/turIDM.js"></script  <script
   src="public/index.js"></script</body</html>
```

When I build this code with webpack, I got the following error
messages:

> ERROR in ./src/index.tsx Module not found: Error: Can't resolve
> 'TurIDM/reducers/Reducers' in
> 'C:\Users\syesilmurat\IdeaProjects\IkizIDM\src'  @ ./src/index.tsx
> 13:17-52  @ multi ./src/index.tsx ./turIDM/turIDM.scss
>
> ERROR in ./src/index.tsx Module not found: Error: Can't resolve
> 'TurIDM/containers/Main' in
> 'C:\Users\syesilmurat\IdeaProjects\IkizIDM\src'  @ ./src/index.tsx
> 14:13-46  @ multi ./src/index.tsx ./turIDM/turIDM.scss
>
> ERROR in ./src/index.tsx Module not found: Error: Can't resolve
> 'TurIDM/containers/LoginContainer' in
> 'C:\Users\syesilmurat\IdeaProjects\IkizIDM\src'  @ ./src/index.tsx
> 15:23-66  @ multi ./src/index.tsx ./turIDM/turIDM.scss
>
> ERROR in ./src/index.tsx Module not found: Error: Can't resolve
> 'TurIDM/util/Constants' in
> 'C:\Users\syesilmurat\IdeaProjects\IkizIDM\src'  @ ./src/index.tsx
> 16:18-50  @ multi ./src/index.tsx ./turIDM/turIDM.scss Child
> extract-text-webpack-plugin:
> [0] ./~/css-loader/lib/css-base.js 2.26 kB {0} [built]
> [1] ./~/css-loader!./~/sass-loader/lib/loader.js!./turIDM/turIDM.scss

When I generate .d.ts file for each ts file in the same hierarchy and put them under "nodeModules" as shown below, it works. (To do that I added "declaration: true" under "compilerOptions" in tsconfig.json.).
Basically, each module definition is searched in a .d.ts file placed with certain folder hierarchy.

```
Project
   - nodeModules
     - TurIDM
      - actions
        Action.d.ts
        ActionTypes.d.ts
      - components
         // Some .d.ts files
      - containers
         // Some .d.ts files
      - reducers
        Reducers.d.ts
```

But this is not what I want exactly. I want to generate one .d.ts and one .js file for my library to be used by external projects. Is it possible? If so, how? :)

tsconfig.json:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "./public",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "es5",
        "jsx": "react",
        "lib": [
            "es6",
            "es7",
            "dom"
        ],
        "declaration": true,
        "exclude": [
            "node_modules",
            "public"
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Two things:

I would generate the typings using the compiler itself, no need for external generator. You can do this by adding the `declaration` attribute to the `tsconfig.json`, and please try adding the entry point as the "files" parameter:

```
{
    "files": [
        "./path/to/entry/file"
    ]
    "compilerOptions": {
        "declaration": true
    }
}
```

To specify where the typings are in for the consumers, you need to expand your library's `package.json`

```
{
    "typings": "./path/to/the/generated/index.d.ts"
}
```

This way when using the library in other projects, the types should work just fine.

Comment: First of all, thanks for the reply. I already have declaration:true in my tsconfig.json, but generated index.d.ts file is empty. Basically, my problem is generating a single .d.ts file.

Comment: There is no `"files"` key in your config. Please try adding the entry point as the `"files"` parameter, it should make the  d.ts generation work